# "Inject" OGLES2 shader into OGLES1.1 Application

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I have an android application I am developing for work. It is several thousand rows of code so porting is not an option at this time. Is there a way for me to use GLES20 to create a shader for my application whilst everything else in the app is opengl es 1.1 fixed function ppipeline?

Comment: The hardware that supports only up to OpenGL ES 1.1 is structured for fixed-function OpenGL and don't have the ability to process shaders.

Comment: btw. a little side comment. What is a good polygon count to have in opengl es? Like now I have 50k triangles being rendered with 30 fps. Is that good or crap?